Run Java project on Docker container without Java extension
I have a Java project that I'm writing in VS Code without Java extension and I need to run it on Docker.
I wrote a Dockerfile and ran on Docker but it returns me an error:
*------
 > [3/4] RUN javac CalculatorTest.java:
#6 0.436 /bin/sh: 1: javac: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c javac CalculatorTest.java]: exit code: 127

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim 
WORKDIR /app 
RUN javac CalculatorTest.java 
COPY . . 
CMD ["java","CalculatorTest"]


(1) jre does not include javac (2) You must use JDK instead (3) Or you compile .java into .class first (4) This way you can maintain the original jre.

You're also running javac CalculatorTest.java before you've actually copied that file in.

There are 2 problems here:

You are trying to run javac, which requires a JDK, while you have only installed a JRE.
You run javac before copying your project files into the container, so even if you had the JDK, this wouldnt work.

First, run javac on your local machine to compile you class and generate Calculator.class.
Then run the folowing Dockerfile instead:
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY . .
CMD ["java", "Calculator"]

Next, build your new image and run it in a container with -it, so that you can see whats happening on the inside.
docker build -t my-java-app .
docker run -it --rm my-java-app

DO NOT FORGET THE . ON THE FIRST COMMAND
